# Web Framework that handles forms intuitively?

Tags: frameworks, web-frameworks

Will be starting a web app that will have to provide **many different HTML forms for data entry**, so I was wondering if there is a web framework out there that does this in a clever way. generally when you have forms you have many considerations like navigation, validation, etc. that are not handled very efficiently by he frameworks I've seen so far.

Has someone taken the pain out of forms?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [Grails](http://grails.org/)? It can take your domain classes and dynamically scaffold them into web forms and apply server-side validation. The default scaffolding provides navigation, pagination, validation, and all kinds of other -ations that are pretty good!

Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/).

Answer (score 0):

Try Qcodo.com, It is written in PHP (but fully OOP). It manages both database layer with nice Form templating system.

Answer (score 0):

I think forms are handled pretty cleverly in Ruby on Rails. And also in .Net. The latter goes pretty far in letting you reuse the database logic for validating data and also has "automatic" handling of security issues like XSS and XSRF.